# How to limit Google map size zoom not smaller than screen width/height

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a problem with google map size. The map picture with zoom changing can be smaller than the screen and than I have grey stripes on the top and bottom.

In Google map API they have the same stripes when we use a zoom.
But on https://www.google.com/maps/ there is a limit and we can't make a map smaller than that size.

How I can make such a limit?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [strictBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#MapRestriction.strictBounds), with a bounds latitudes of 85/-85:

```
restriction: {
  latLngBounds: {
    north: 85,
    south: -85,
    west: -180,
    east: 180
  },
  strictBounds: true
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/fgrx5ado/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: -34.397,
      lng: 150.644
    },
    zoom: 1,
    restriction: {
      latLngBounds: {
        north: 85,
        south: -85,
        west: -180,
        east: 180
      },
      strictBounds: true
    }
  });
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```